# Sort dataGridView columns in C# ? (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sorting, grid

I have a datagridview that i bind from an sql table, in that dv i have those attributes: Id, Name and Price. When i set the SortMode of the Name Columns to Automatic and i click on the header of this column i can sort this dv based on the first letter of the Name, this way i can order products based on their first letters ( Acumulator, Boat, CocaCola, Engine etc).

Is there a way this thing to happen without clicking the header of the column Name. I am looking some code that will do this job when the form will load.

Comment: The Answer was: 

this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"],ListSortDirection.Ascending);

Comment: olumnheader click c# datagridview

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There's a method on the DataGridView called "Sort":

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

This will programmatically sort your datagridview.

Comment: what about the time consumed in sorting and he wants to be sorted in the load so what about ordering it when executing the SQL statements not after binding!i think it will consume more time

Comment: Yes, Ahmy is right, performancewise it's probably better to sort it on the database side. Therefore, if you're using SQL to directly interact with the DB, append an order by to the end of your query. I was merely answering the question. This is the way to sort a DGV in code.

Comment: Ok if the AXheladini need that so it's ok but i understood from his question that he does'nt need it in the UI so i wanted to save time at all i am happy that AXheladini find the solution and this what we wish from our answers

Comment: Ahme Your solution its ok, but as i told you i am filling this grid from UI, i am not coding this with c# . By the way your solution works if we do all this job with code. I tried it it works but what i needed was the answer of BFree. 
Any way thanks to all of you that tried to answer this question.

Answer (score 17):

```
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Comment: I agree that using number index better than string index, cause if you change the column name in the future, you will have to change the string index too.

Comment: OTOH if you change the column order.. Now what is more likely??

Answer (score 4):

You can control the data returned from SQL database by ordering the data returned:

```
orderby [Name]
```

If you execute the SQL query from your application, order the data returned. For example, make a function that calls the procedure or executes the SQL and give it a parameter that gets the orderby criteria. Because if you ordered the data returned from database it will consume time but order it since it's executed as you say that you want it to be ordered not from the UI you want it to be ordered in the run time so order it when executing the SQL query.

Comment: I am binding the datagridview automaticlly i dont use query. 
Is there a way to access the query of the datasource and correct this ?

Comment: i mean that the SQL statement that query the database and return the data add to it the syntax orderby in the procedure u use or in SQL statement in the DAL layer

Answer (score 4):

This one is simplier :)

```
dataview dataview1; 
this.dataview1= dataset.tables[0].defaultview;
this.dataview1.sort = "[ColumnName] ASC, [ColumnName] DESC";
this.datagridview.datasource = dataview1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to sort the list before binding data source.

`cars = cars.OrderBy(o => o.year).ThenBy(o => o.color).ToList();
adgCars.DataSource = cars;`

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Datatable.Default.Sort` property and then bind it to the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 solutions to this problem.

**1. Sort (DataGridViewColumn column, ListSortDirection direction) function**

This function can be used to sort a column alphabetically or numerically or by date in descending or ascending order.

example:

```
dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[5],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

**2. Sort (IComparer comparer) function**

This function can be use for all other situations as

Sorting a column with specific order that is different than numeric order (example: sorting an amount that can be negative or positive using only absolute values)

Sorting a column with specific order that is different than alphabetic order (example: sorting a text using case insensitive sort)

Sorting multiples columns as sorting a table using AMOUNT column as first column and DATE column as second column.

VB.Net example:

```
Private Sub pbSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
    Handles pbSort.Click

    grid.Sort(New AmountDateComparer(Me))
End Sub

Private Class AmountDateComparer : Implements IComparer

    Private frm As FrmSearch

    Public Sub New(frm As FrmSearch)
        Me.frm = frm
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(x1 As Object, x2 As Object) As Integer _
        Implements IComparer.Compare

        Dim row1 As DataGridViewRow = x1
        Dim row2 As DataGridViewRow = x2

        ' compare AMOUNT values of columns

        Dim nAmount1 = Convert.ToDecimal(row1.Cells(frm.Col_AMOUNT.Index).Value)
        Dim nAmount2 = Convert.ToDecimal(row2.Cells(frm.Col_AMOUNT.Index).Value)

        Dim iCompareResult As Integer 
            = System.Decimal.Compare(nAmount1, nAmount2)

        If iCompareResult = 0 Then
            'compare DATE values of columns
            Dim d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(row1.Cells(frm.Col_DATE.Index).Value)
            Dim d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(row2.Cells(frm.Col_DATE.Index).Value)

            iCompareResult = System.DateTime.Compare(d1, d2)
        End If

        Return iCompareResult
    End Function
End Class
```