# Error while sorting the data in gridview - > DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am developing the windows application in VB.NET.
I have collection of records and I had bind the collection of records to the 
Datagridview.

I am able to bind the data to grid successfully.

Now, I am trying to sort the Grid view with below line of code...

I have refer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806725/sort-datagridview-colums-in-c-sharp-windows-form)...

but it gives an error....

> DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be
>   sorted.

I have below code...

```
Try

            DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            Dim oEmployees As New Employees
            oEmployees.LoadAllRegularEmployees()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = oEmployees
            Me.DataGridView1.Sort(Me.DataGridView1.Columns("IDEmp"), ListSortDirection.Ascending)

      Catch ex As Exception

      End Try
```

Whats the issue ?

> Is there any way to perform this without using SortableBindingList  ?

Comment: `Employees` must implement the `IBindingList` interface (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) OR you set `VirtualMode` to false (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Thanks..but How to do that ? Is there any example of it ?

Comment: Try using a BindingSource for your Employees since it implements the IBindingList:
`Dim oEmployees As New Employees
    Dim EmployeeBinding As New BindingSource(oEmployees)
     DataGridView1.DataSource = EmployeeBinding`

Comment: Tried above solutions, throwing an error, -> Unable to cast object of type 'elEntity.BusinessObjects.Employees' to type 'System.ComponentModel.IContainer'.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please cerate a new BindingSource using the parameterless constructor and set the DS afterwards: 
`Dim EmployeeBinding As New BindingSource()
         EmployeeBinding.DataSource = oEmployees
  DataGridView1.DataSource = EmployeeBinding` 
I cant test it right now don´t have access to a VS.

Comment: Ok, I will try, but why I cant use simple sort technique like Datagridview.Sort = "columnName" something like this ? I have saw many examples of it...

Comment: Because .NET was desgined that way? I´m really curious which exmaples you found working just with .Sort without a BindingSource ....

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()

        Do While i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count

            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value, DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value)


            i = i + 1
        Loop
        ' i= DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

        DataGridView2.Sort(DataGridView2.Columns(3), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```