# How to sort DataGridView ascending and descending in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

How to sort DataGridView ascending and descending in a C# desktop application?

I just mapped the list to Data Grid View source

```
List<Lecturer> lecList = new Lecturer().getAllLecturers();
   dgvLecturer.DataSource = lecList;
```

Comment: You can also sort your list before binding it to DataGrid: e.g: `lecList.OrderBy(x=>x.Id);` or `lecList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id);` and then pass it to DataSource.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661195/datagridview-using-sortablebindinglist

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView's `Sort` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

try looking at the code in this question:
[Sort dataGridView columns in C# ? (Windows Form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806725/sort-datagridview-colums-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

Comment: I tried that already, id doesn't work :(

Comment: I got this error "DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted".