# C# Questions Concerning DataGridView-sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to sort the `DataGridView` by column - I want to do this using code so that one of my methods can sort the `DataGridView`. (Same effect as if the user clicks on the column header, but without the clicking.)
2. When I sort a column with `decimal` values (of type `double`) the sorting believes that 9.99 is larger than 24.99 - is there any way to prevent this type of sorting behaviour?

Update: Question number 1 was solved thanks to a link in the comments.
I also found the cause of the issue to question number 2: The values in my column are `(double)price + "€"`. I tried removing the `+ "€"` and it started sorting the way I want.
Now I want it to be able to sort, while keeping the € somehow.

Comment: For the sorting, the below question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956251/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-programmatically

Comment: Can you show us the code/xaml for that column to see how the data is going in/being formatted?

Comment: First question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806725/sort-datagridview-colums-in-c-sharp-windows-form

Comment: You need to show what you've tried with sorting. As @Josh said, how you're putting the data into the DataGridView. Remove the first question as each question should only be a single question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first question was correctly covered by stuartd, we'll focus on the second:

> When I sort a column with `decimal` values (of type `double`) the sorting believes that 9.99 is larger than 24.99 - is there any way to prevent this type of sorting behaviour?

As you've noticed, removing `+ "€"` corrected your issue because *with it* that column is performing a `string` comparison instead of the intended `double` comparison. You can fix this by using a [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to format the column as a currency column instead.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = ci.NumberFormat;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

[image: unsorted list] [image: sort asc] [image: sort desc]