# C# order column by date - header column datetime

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

we try to sort the column of my datagridview in C# from the most recent to the other, but i didn't find a solution.

Below the image of my little program 
[references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFBO.png)

my last test it's to use:

```
      for (int i=1; i<dsForecast.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = dsForecast.Columns[i];
            dtListDate.Add(DateTime.Parse(col.ColumnName));
        }

        Dictionary<DateTime, int> dList = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dtListDate.Count; i++)
            dList.Add(dtListDate[i], i);

        dtListDate.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));


        foreach (DataColumn c in dsForecast.Columns)
            this.dgwForecast.Columns[c.ColumnName].DisplayIndex = dsForecast.Columns.IndexOf(c);
```

Can anyone help  me to find a solution for this?

i want a result like this,[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsnRX.png)

I undestrand that the solution is to move the columnn with its contents, but how?

Can someone Help me?

Comment: are you sure you dont need something like `dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);` ? because all i read is you want to sort by a column which contains date?  take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/806793/3956100

Comment: Yes, I try this, but i must order the column, not the value of the column,.....