# How to order Datatable by row value?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have the below datatable, how can I sort the datatable by Today name, so for example if today is Monday, it should show at the end of the Datatable

I tried the following, but it is not working

```
Dim dv As DataView = dt3.DefaultView
    dv.Sort = " DayLog desc"
    Dim sortedDT = dv.ToTable()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to sort the rows in the database table itself (hard way) or only in the gridview? You can also sort the DataSource using an orderby in the sql or linq request. For only the gridview you can use datagrid behavior using sort method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806725/sort-datagridview-columns-in-c-sharp-windows-form | Or let the user click on the column to sort by it: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-sorting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Comment: no, I want to sort it in the Datatable itself, as I am using a chart to display the day's data, and I want today's data to show at the end of the chart

Comment: To sort rows in the database table structure itself, you may create a temp table, insert rows sorted, delete rows in the source table and reinject sorted rows in the table. What is the DB Server and how do you access to it (what is the data provider)?

Comment: Concerning the sort itself, you may implement the sort to compare DayOfWeek int value or a thing like that like comparing strings names... https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Is there any underlying data which has the actual dates in, not just the day of the week?

Comment: Do you mean you want it ordered Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, Monday?

Answer (score 1):

Been some time since I've done some VB, surely you could do the following?

```
Dim data() AS DataRow = dt.Select()
Dim sortedData = data.OrderBy(Function(x) CInt([Enum].Parse(GetType(DayOfWeek), x.Item("DayLog"))) )

Dim sortedDataTable = dt.Clone()

For Each row In sortedData
    sortedDataTable.ImportRow(row)
Next
```

**Assuming the spelling of your days of the week is 100% correct**

If you have the string value of the current day of the week or you know the int value, then you can adjust the sort using modulus

eg.

```
Dim todayStringVal = "Tuesday" // say you have this value from somewhere
Dim today = CInt([Enum].Parse(GetType(DayOfWeek), todayStringVal)) // convert to day of the week enum
Dim sortedData = data.OrderBy(Function(x) CInt(([Enum].Parse(GetType(DayOfWeek), x.Item("DayLog")) + 7 - today)) Mod 7) // Apply sorting
```

Finally if you want the above snippet to sort so that `today`'s value is at the end of the list just change `OrderBy` to `OrderByDescending`

EDIT

To ensure `today`'s value appears first in your list even though `DayOfWeek`'s index starts at 0 you need to + 7 and subtract the index then mod by 7 to get the correct index to sort by

eg. Saturday's index on the `DayOfWeek` enum is 6 therefore 6 + 7 (Days of the week) = 13 then subtract by 6 = 7 finally 7 mod 7 is 0, so Saturday's new index becomes 0 and gets ordered first in the list